# How to prevent the conversion of text URL to link?

Tags: 8, navigation

I am creating a basic page having some text links as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/student
http://localhost:8080
http://localhost:8080/login
```

D8 automatically converts this text URL to links as follows

http://localhost:8080/sutdent

http://localhost:8080

http://localhost:8080/login

I don't want to convert the text URLs to links. I also checked the text filters but did not work for me.
[image]
How to prevent this conversion?

Comment: If this is the body od the node then a) the input filter for converting links is active or b) yo uare using wysiwyg(ckeditor) and it converts is on its own(or c) you are pasting it as link instead of text).

Comment: @IvanJaros I'm passing URL as text not link..

Comment: When editing the node, do you have correct input filter selected? Also, isn't the content already saved? Meaning the link is already in the db? Try creating a new node or edit the soruce code directly(if you have ckeditor).

Comment: Filters in text formats are used to format output. Cache needs to be cleared too after re-configuring text formats. I don't think the Cache context is invalidated when the text format changes...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not a problem if you a using CKeditor.

I tried to write some text URLs in both `Basic HTML` and `Full HTML` format. It worked fine, if you want to see how I did I have made a little video for you:

https://vimeo.com/234845994

Comment: I have tried this on a fresh drupal 8 installation and it works fine ☺

Comment: I need full HTML format..

Comment: Ok try to write the link text and then change the a tags to p tags in the source code and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in D7.  Not sure if it's related.  I am not exactly sure what fixed it but I did completely uninstall and them re-install filter_module.  I also had to restart apache to clear out some caching there.

All my settings were like yours with convert URLS to links disabled.  Did not matter what text format or WYSIWYG editor I used.  I always cleared Drupal cache after making changes and used browser in incognito mode to make sure there was no caching.